# Проблема при записи кирилицы в CSV

Tags: python, csv

Написал код, работает но есть одна проблема. При записи в CSV он записывает по одной букве в каждый столбик. В чем проблема - не знаю, надеюсь на вашу помощь)

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep


URL = 'https://oz.by/books/topic11.html?page=1'
r = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
items = soup.find_all('div', class_="item-type-card")

with open("books.csv", "w", encoding="cp1251") as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow(
        (
            "Название",
            "Автор",
            "Цена",
        )
    )
for x in range(1):
    URL = f'https://oz.by/books/topic11.html?page={x}'
    r = requests.get(URL)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
    items = soup.find_all('div', class_="item-type-card")
    sleep(1)

    for i in items:
        try:
            book = i.find('p', class_="item-type-card__title").text
            author = i.find('p', class_="item-type-card__info").text
            price = i.find('span', class_="item-type-card__btn").text

            with open("books.csv", "a", encoding='cp1251') as file:
                writer = csv.writer(file)
                writer.writerows(
                    (
                        book,
                        author,
                        price
                    )
                )

        except AttributeError:
            pass
```

[image: Вот картинка]

Comment: а где вы видите проблемы с кодировкой?

Comment: Покажите CSV как текст и как HEX. А то мало ли что там Excel удумал... может, у него текущая спецификация импорта такая.

Answer (score 1):

На сколько я понял, Вы результат потом будете в Excel открывать.
Ниже полностью совместимый с MS Excel вариант.

> Собираем данные в список словарей, затем записываем через `csv.DictWriter()` в `unix` диалекте с кодировкой `utf-8-sig` что соответсвует (`UTF-8 With BOM`)

```py
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep
from unicodedata import normalize


URL = 'https://oz.by/books/topic11.html'
r = requests.get(URL, params={'page': 1})
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
items = soup.find_all('div', class_="item-type-card")

headers = ["Название", "Автор", "Цена"]

rows = []

for x in range(1):
    
    r = requests.get(URL, params={'page': x})
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    items = soup.find_all('div', class_="item-type-card")
    sleep(1)

    for i in items:
        try:
            book = normalize('NFKC', i.find('p', class_="item-type-card__title").get_text(strip=True))
            author = normalize('NFKC', i.find('p', class_="item-type-card__info").get_text(strip=True))
            price = normalize('NFKC', i.find('span', class_="item-type-card__btn").get_text(strip=True))

            rows.append(
                dict(zip(headers, [book, author, price]))
            )

        except AttributeError:
            pass
with open("books.csv", "w", encoding='utf-8-sig', newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames=headers, dialect=csv.unix_dialect)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(
        rows
    )
```

### UPD

#### В качестве бонуса, почти Ваш код с пагинацией

```py
import csv

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup
from requests import Session
from tqdm.auto import tqdm
from unicodedata import normalize

URL = 'https://oz.by/books/topic11.html'

headers = ["Название", "Автор", "Цена"]
rows = []

s = Session()


def get_content(page: int):
    response = s.get(URL, params={'page': page})
    soup = Soup(response.content, 'html.parser')

    for item in soup.find_all('div', class_="item-type-card"):
        if book := normalize('NFKC', elem.get_text(strip=True)) if (
        elem := item.find('p', class_="item-type-card__title")) else '':
            rows.append(
                dict(
                    zip(
                        headers,
                        [
                            book,
                            normalize('NFKC', elem.get_text(strip=True)) if (
                                elem := item.find('p', class_="item-type-card__info")) else '',
                            normalize('NFKC', elem.get_text(strip=True)) if (
                                elem := item.find('span', class_="item-type-card__btn")) else ''
                        ]
                    )
                )
            )

    return int(soup.find('li', class_='pg-last').get('data-value', 1))


for i in tqdm(range(2, get_content(1) + 1)):
    get_content(i)

with open("books.csv", "w", encoding='utf-8-sig', newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames=headers, dialect=csv.unix_dialect)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(
        rows
    )
```

Comment: Потестил ваш скрипт, оч понравилось, правда я новичок и что-то непонятно, можем мы пообщаться в телеграме например?